# Making a recursive algorithm for converting URL string into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, urldecode

I found myself having to process a string like:

```
foo=bar&foo1=foo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dfoo%253Dbar
```

Into:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo1": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "foo2": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

[A real input example.](https://gist.github.com/avi12/cd1d6728445608d64475809a8ddccc9c)

My best attempt is:

```js
function parse(input) {
  try {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(input);
    return parseJSON(parsed);
  } catch (err) {
    const decodedInput = decodeURIComponent(input);
    if (input.includes("&") && input.includes("=")) {
      return input.split("&").reduce((json, part) => {
        const [key, value] = part.split("=");
        const decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(value);
        return { ...json, [key]: parsePrimitive(decodedValue) };
      }, {});
    }
    return decodedInput;
  }
}

function parsePrimitive(input) {
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    return Number(input);
  }
  if (input === "true" || input === "false") {
    return input === "true";
  }
  return parse(input);
}

function parseJSON(input) {
  return Object.entries(input).reduce((json, [key, value]) => {
    let object = {};
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        object[key] = value;
      } else {
        object[key] = parseJSON(value);
      }
    } else {
      const decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(value);
      if (decodedValue.includes("&") && decodedValue.includes("=")) {
        object[key] = parse(decodedValue);
      } else {
        object[key] = parsePrimitive(decodedValue);
      }
    }
    return { ...json, ...object };
  }, {});
}
```

If you try to run it, you're supposed to call `parse(input)`
However, it does fail for certain inputs

How can I make the perfect recursive algorithm for this kind of problem?
Thanks!

Comment: are you running this from within a browser or on a nodejs server?

Comment: Node.js server.

Comment: node.js comes with URL parse capabilities with: 
const url = require('url'); 
which you can use to return an object of the query params immediately:
const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
then just modify the object as needed.
more here: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/

Comment: It doesn't seem to work recursively properly

Comment: looking at the example you added, you have different types of params in your main URL parameters. Some of them are objects [like player_response], some more URL params [like web_api_url, which will need recursion] and some are lists separated by commas [like fexp]. So I would create a function to check each of those types - will add the code I used to your gist

Comment: The functions I gave can technically handle this URL input, but it's not guaranteed that they will work for any kind of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked the algorithm using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)(new [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)()).

```js
function parse(query) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(query);
  } catch {
    if (!isNaN(query)) {
      return Number(query);
    }

    if (typeof query !== "string") {
      const obj = {};
      for (const queryKey in query) {
        if (query.hasOwnProperty(queryKey)) {
          obj[queryKey] = parse(query[queryKey]);
        }
      }

      return obj;
    }
    if (!query) {
      return "";
    }

    if (query.toLowerCase().match(/^(true|false)$/)) {
      return query.toLowerCase() === "true";
    }

    const object = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(query));
    const values = Object.values(object);
    if (values.length === 1 && values[0] === "") {
      return query;
    }
    return parse(object);
  }
}



const q = 'foo=bar&foo1=foo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dfoo%253Dbar';
console.log(parse(q));

console.log('fetching larger example...');

fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/avi12/cd1d6728445608d64475809a8ddccc9c/raw/030974baed3eaadb26d9378979b83b1d30a265a3/url-input-example.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(parse)
  .then(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by checking the encoded `=` sign.

```js
const getValues = string => string.split('&')
    .reduce((r, pair) => {
      let [key, value] = pair.split('=');
      value = decodeURIComponent(value);
      r[key] = value.includes('=')
        ? getValues(value)
        : value;
      return r;
    }, {});

console.log(getValues('foo=bar&foo1=foo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dfoo%253Dbar'));
```

Comment: I noticed that you first begin with `.split("&")`, to process the encoded URL. However, I can't guarantee that a string will have both a `&` and `=`, hence in my code I'm checking for the presence of both

Comment: what happens if the string does not contain `'='`?

Comment: Just tested your code with my input, and it doesn't process some of it correctly

Comment: please add some more examples.

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it for your simple example and your [more complex one](https://gist.github.com/avi12/cd1d6728445608d64475809a8ddccc9c) (now **updated** to handle numbers and booleans):

```js
const parse = (query) =>
  query .startsWith ('{')
    ? JSON .parse (query)
  : query .includes ('&') || query .includes ('=')
    ? Object .fromEntries (
        query .split ('&') 
          .map (p => p .split ('='))
          .map (([k, v]) => [k, parse (decodeURIComponent (v))])
      )
  : query .includes (',')
    ? query .split (',') .filter (Boolean) .map (parse)
  : isFinite (query)
    ? Number (query)
  : query .toLowerCase () == "true" || query .toLowerCase () == "false"
    ? query .toLowerCase () == "true"
  : // else
    query


const q = 'foo=bar&foo1=foo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dfoo%253Dbar'
console .log (parse(q))

console.log('fetching larger example...')

fetch ('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/avi12/cd1d6728445608d64475809a8ddccc9c/raw/030974baed3eaadb26d9378979b83b1d30a265a3/url-input-example.txt')
  .then (res => res .text ())
  .then (parse)
  .then (console .log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

There are two parts that deserve attention.

First, this makes an assumption about commas: that they represent a separation between elements of an array.  And, further, it assumes that empty strings aren't intended, turning

```js
watermark=%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png
%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png
```

into this:

```
watermark: [
  "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png",
  "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png"
]
```

The original starts with an encoded comma (`%2C`), which would lead to an initial empty string, so we use `.filter (Boolean)` to remove it.

Second, the test for a string representing JSON is very naïve, only doing `.startsWith ('{')`.  You can replace this with whatever you need, but it leads to a question of intentions.  I'm not sure we can write this entirely generically in this manner.

Still, I think it's close.  And the code is fairly clean.

---

I do have to wonder *why*, however.  This much data is going to run into various url size limits.  At this point, wouldn't putting this into a request body rather than url parameters make much more sense?

Comment: It would be helpful if your recursion could also parse booleans and numbers

Comment: @avi12: Updated to handle those.  But note that this now makes `fexp` into an array of numbers, although it *looks* more like an array of numeric ids.  It will do this elsewhere, too.  Although this may do what you want now, it's hard to know if it can cover all cases.  It also will auto-convert all "true" and "false" strings to booleans, even if that's not desired.

Comment: `Boolean(query)` will never produce `false`, so the best boolean conversion would be `query.toLowerCase() === "true"`

Comment: Oops, yes.  Fixed.

Comment: @avi12: I've rejected edits changing this from a plain-expression style function into a function declaration with `if-else`s in place of the conditional (ternary) expressions.  If that's what you prefer, please add another answer with it (and accept that one if you prefer it.)  The style here is very much intended.  I prefer to work with expressions than statements whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js comes with a built-in "querystring" npm package utility, but here I used a better one called "qs". You can specify delimiters in an array instead of only using one with the former.

If you want to use the built-in "querystring" package, you need to remove the delimiter array when calling parse and do a check on the string to see what delimiter is used - the sample file you gave use a few different ones.

So try this:

```
const qs = require("qs");
let params = `foo=bar&foo1=foo%3Dbar%26foo2%3Dfoo%253Dbar`;

const isObject = (param) => {
  try {
    let testProp = JSON.parse(param);
    if (typeof testProp === "object" && testProp !== null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

const isURL = (value) => {
  try {
    new URL(value);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const isQueryString = (value) => {
  if (/[/&=]/.test(value) && !isURL(value)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const parseData = (data, parsed = false) => {
  if (isQueryString(data) && !parsed) {
    return parseData(qs.parse(data, { delimiter: /[;,/&]/ }), true);
  } else if (isObject(data) || parsed) {
    for (let propertyName in data) {
      if (isObject(data[propertyName])) {
        data[propertyName] = parseData(JSON.parse(data[propertyName]), true);
      } else {
        data[propertyName] = parseData(data[propertyName]);
      }
    }

    return data;
  } else {
    return data;
  }
};
let s = parseData(params);
console.log(JSON.stringify(s, null, 2));
```